# How to stop automatic rounding in mutate verb when dividing two columns of a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rounding

I am trying to add a new column by dividing column A and Column B using mutate() verb in R.

```
dataframe %>%
    mutate(colC = colA / colB)
```

But the new value in Column C is automatically getting rounded off to two decimal places. How do I avoid that from happening?

Manually dividing the value in the console is giving proper output up to ten decimal places.

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6283 | 4835 | 1.30 |
| 5784 | 4567 | 1.27 |

In normal console:
6283 / 4835 -->
1.2994829369183040768

5784 / 4567 -->
1.2664768994963870874

Comment: Please show what command you are actually running. Also, the output is just being truncated, the same level of precision is still being used in the calculation.

Comment: I am using a normal mutate() syntax. 
dataframe %>% mutate(colC = colA / colB)

Comment: This is just the rendering in your console for `tibbles`, the dataframe format in the tidyverse. If you use ColC again, it will use the un-rounded values.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what is actually happening.

```
dplyr_res = df %>% mutate(ColC = ColA / ColB) %>% pull(ColC) %>% .[1]
```

```
  ColA ColB     ColC
1 6283 4835 1.299483
2 5784 4567 1.266477
```

```
base_res = 6283 / 4835
```

```
> identical(base_res, dplyr_res)
[1] TRUE
```

They are identical, the output is just truncated.

Comment: Got it. I actually saved the output in the new dataframe and on looking at view(dataframe) shows entire decimal values.

Comment: [What should I do if someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).